# Loop on table to create Dynamic Layers

Tags: loop, dynamic, create, layer-name

I am receiving a table with customer names, group of customers and some data.
I need to create dynamically Layers of these groups, then add these customer to these respective groups, then display a default base layer with the possibility to tick also a group layer.
I am good with most of it except "create dynamically Layers from a table of string".
The declaration or creation of Layers is wrong the syntax probably or a missing part.

```
...
```

```
    function hide_marker( xxLayer, xxChecked ) {
        console.info("hide_marker: "+xxLayer);  
         if( !xxChecked ){
            mymap.removeLayer(xxLayer);               
         }else
         {
            mymap.addLayer(xxLayer);               
         }
    }

    var locationsCust = [
                     ["Group1", "Cust1", "Address Cust1", 50.00000000, 10.00000000,"00FF00"]
                    ,["Group1", "Cust2", "Address Cust2", 50.00000000, 11.00000000,"00FF00"]
                    ,["Group2", "Cust3", "Address Cust3", 50.00000000, 12.00000000,"00FF00"]
                    ];  


    var legendrows = '';
    var rowidNameGroup;    
    var layerAllCust= L.layerGroup();
    var mbUrl  = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';
        mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                    '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                    'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>';

    var mapView        = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr});

    var layerName = '';

    var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
        center: [50, 10],
        zoom: 5,
        layers: [mapView, layerAllCust]
    });

    L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {
        maxZoom: 10,
        attribution: mbAttr,
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(mymap);               

    var overlays = {
        "Cust": layerAllCust
    };

    var baseLayers = {
        "Map": mapView
    };

    **var overlayMaps = {};**

    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    for (var i = 0; i < locationsCust.length; i++)
    {
        var locData = locationsCust[i];
        var Icon = L.IconMaterial.icon({
            markerColor: '#'+locData[5],  // Marker fill color
            outlineColor: 'black',        // Marker outline color
            outlineWidth: 1,              // Marker outline width 
        })

        L.marker( [locData[3], locData[4]] , {icon: Icon})
            .bindPopup(locData[1])
            .addTo( layerAllCust);

        if (rowidNameGroup != locData[0])
        {                   
            rowidNameGroup = locData[0];
            **overlayMaps[layerName] = "POP"+i;**
            //add the layer to the overlayMaps with a dynamic layer name                
            legendrows = legendrows + "<span class='xxLegendeTableCell'>"
                                    +"<input type=checkbox class='xxVBID' onClick='hide_marker(overlayMaps[layerName], this.checked);' />"
                                    +"<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=|"+locData[5]+"|000000' width='11' height='17'></img>"+rowidNameGroup+"</span>";
            console.info("Layer :"+overlayMaps[layerName]);  
            **<!-- L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayMaps).addTo(mymap);  -->**
        }
    }
    ...
```